# Hide particular word using css or javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I tried the below code to add div id and replace div class from basic text to heading h3 well it worked but it started displaying all the domain names in the table of contents before the heading.

as ......com with the title text
I want to hide anything which displays with .com

```
<h3 class="producttitle">
            <?php if ($merchant = TemplateHelper::getMerhantName($item)): ?>
                <div class="cegg-mb10">
                    <small class="text-muted title-case"><?php echo \esc_html($merchant); ?></small>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ($item['rating']): ?>
                <div class="cegg-title-rating">
                    <?php TemplateHelper::printRating($item, 'small'); ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php echo \esc_html(TemplateHelper::truncate($item['title'], 80)); ?>
        </h3>
```

I want this code but at the same time i want to hide it in the table of contents from so and so domain .com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I fixed it! Now the domain names has gone and headings are working perfectly.

```
<h3 class="producttitle">
        <?php if ($title = TemplateHelper::getMerhantName($item)): ?>
            
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ($item['rating']): ?>
            <div class="cegg-title-rating">
                <?php TemplateHelper::printRating($item, ''); ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php echo \esc_html(TemplateHelper::truncate($item['title'], 80)); ?>
    </h3>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).